# How to reference previous records in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

For simplicity, let's say I have a table like this.

```sql
| id    |  a     |   b  |  c   |
| 1     | 100    |  b1  | c1   |
| 2     | 104    |  b2  | c2   |
| 3     | 106    |  b1  | c1   |
| 5     | 118    |  b2  | c2   |
```

I want to find next record which field ***b*** and ***c*** share the same value as previous one, and field ***a*** is greater than previous one. There may be more than one records match that, but I only want to get the first one which matches it.
I do not know how to write such a SQL to get result like below.
i.e.:

```sql
| id    |  a     |   b    |  c   | matched_id. | b(1) | c(1) |
| 1     | 100    |  b1    | c1   |   3         | b1   |  c1  |
| 2     | 104    |  b2    | c2   |   5         | b2   |  c2  |
| 3     | 106    |  b1    | c1   |   null      | null |  null|
| 5     | 118    |  b2    | c2   |   null      | null |  null|
```

BTW, I am using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: so you want to select min(a) where a > previous.a and b=previous.b and c=previous.c?

Comment: Right. It seems simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to join again with the same table on b = b and c = c, and then I do not know how to proceed. What if i can use camparision operator after `on`.

Comment: Start working in parts.  First select records where a > previous a (trivial), then figure out how to find where b is equal to the previous one (Google), then do C  and finally put them together.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a self join and ROW_NUMBER to get only the first, whuich will work only in MySQL 8.

To show that it works i added another row with id 6

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `a` INTEGER,
>   `b` VARCHAR(4),
>   `c` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`id`, `a`, `b`, `c`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '100', 'b1', 'c1'),
>   ('2', '104', 'b2', 'c2'),
>   ('3', '106', 'b1', 'c1'),
>   ('5', '118', 'b2', 'c2'),
>    ('6', '120', 'b1', 'c1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`,`id(1)`, `b(1)`, `c(1)`
> FROM
> (SELECT t1.id,t1.a,t1.b,t1.c
> ,t2.id `id(1)`
> ,t2.b as `b(1)`
> ,t2.c `c(1)`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id,t2.id) rn
> FROM tab1 t1 LEFT JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c and t1.id<t2.id) t3
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> id |   a | b  | c  | id(1) | b(1) | c(1)
> -: | --: | :- | :- | ----: | :--- | :---
>  1 | 100 | b1 | c1 |     3 | b1   | c1  
>  2 | 104 | b2 | c2 |     5 | b2   | c2  
>  3 | 106 | b1 | c1 |     6 | b1   | c1  
>  5 | 118 | b2 | c2 |  null | null | null
>  6 | 120 | b1 | c1 |  null | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad30f29f552c85b49b493dab2415f917)*

## MySQL 5.7 version

> ```
> SELECT 
> `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`,`id(1)`, `b(1)`, `c(1)`
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`,`id(1)`, `b(1)`, `c(1)`
> ,if (@t1id = id, @rn := @rn+1, @rn := 1) rn
> , @t1id := id
> FROM
> (SELECT t1.id,t1.a,t1.b,t1.c
> ,t2.id `id(1)`
> ,t2.b as `b(1)`
> ,t2.c `c(1)`
> FROM tab1 t1 LEFT JOIN tab1 t2 ON t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c and t1.id<t2.id
> ORDER BY t1.id,t2.id
> LIMIT 100000) t5
> ,(SELECT @t1id := 0, @rn := 0) t4) t6
> WHERE rn = 1
> ORDER BY id
> ```

> ```
> id |   a | b  | c  | id(1) | b(1) | c(1)
> -: | --: | :- | :- | ----: | :--- | :---
>  1 | 100 | b1 | c1 |     3 | b1   | c1  
>  2 | 104 | b2 | c2 |     5 | b2   | c2  
>  3 | 106 | b1 | c1 |     6 | b1   | c1  
>  5 | 118 | b2 | c2 |  null | null | null
>  6 | 120 | b1 | c1 |  null | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dded9558b9b18294c74cddc1aabdbdc6)*

Comment: Thx for your answer. But it is a pity `select ROW_NUMBER()` is not supported on MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @Gorgine i added a mysql 5.7 Version

Comment: It will match all records, not the first one.

Comment: yes sorry mysql 5.7 is really old and i haven't programmed it for a while, see the changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use LATERAL, that makes things easy IMHO:

```
select t1.*, tt.id matched_id, tt.b b1, tt.c c1
 from myTable t1
 left outer join lateral 
 (select * from myTable t2
    where t1.b = t2.b and t1.c = t2.c and t2.a > t1.a
    limit 1
 ) tt on true
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=066722abf73ddbce9093f0d1de784edd)

EDIT: I didn't notice it was 5.7 before, sorry. Here is an 5.7 version:

```
select tmp.*, t3.b b1, t3.c c1
from (select id, b, c, 
  (select min(id) 
   from myTable t2 
   where t1.b = t2.b and t1.c = t2.c and t2.a > t1.a) as matched_id
 from myTable t1) tmp
 left join myTable t3 on t3.id = tmp.matched_id;
```

Comment: It will match all records.

Comment: @Gorgine, what do you mean?

Comment: If b and c both match the record a, then there will be two records both with id = a.id.

Comment: @Gorgine, sorry I can't understand what you mean. b, c match a ? What does that mean in the first place?

Comment: It's ok now, maybe I see something wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked with me:

```
SELECT p.id, p.a, p.b, p.c, matched_id.id,matched_id.b, matched_id.c 
FROM test p left join test matched_id on  
    matched_id.a = (select min(a) 
                    from test m 
                    where m.a>p.a and m.b=p.b and m.c = p.c);
```

There were some trial and error on this, so it's not so clean, sorry.

db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6w4NsFzCi6Qm4sfUgkKLgf/0